# how to pass a parameter from an URL to a XSL stylesheet using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xslt

I have something like this:

```
$('#output').xslt({xml: 'x',xslUrl: 'Test.xsl'});
```

How do I pass a parameter to the Test.xsl file and retreive the same url in the xsl file?

I am using the jquery libraries: `jquery.1.1.3.js` and [`jquery.xslt.js`](http://www.jongma.org/webtools/jquery/xslt/)

Or is there any way I could send a parameter to my xsl file via js or jQuery ?

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Used another jQuery library which provided an option to pass parameters to the XSL file:

- `jquery-1.3.2.min.js`
- `jquery.transform.js`

Code:

```
$.transform({
  datatype : "xml",
  el       : "#output",
  async    : false, 
  xmlstr   : [ xmlDoc ], 
  xsl      : 'Test.xsl', 
  xslParams: {
    abc: "value",
    pqr: "valu2"
  }
});
```

Using `xslParams` I can pass the parameters. Using `<xsl:param>` I can retrieve the parameters in my XSL:

```
<xsl:param name="abc" />
```

This `<xsl:param>` must be globally declared in your XSL.

Answer (score 1):

Add the URL to the XML file you are transforming with the XSL stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation, it simply doesn't look like parameters / external inputs are supported.

Comment: but the library uses xslProcessor() and u can add a parameter via this function .. so there must be a way out